# How to add information from a database into a html table using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am super new to this rails so please be gentle :)

I have a html table in my app, Simple right? All i need to do is get the information from the table in the database into a table (the database is already connected up as its being added to an existing application.)

I believe i tried to do it right haha! heres what i had and what happened

i had this in my controller

```
def data
    @data = CarStatus.all
  end
```

I was under the impression that this would get all the rows in the conference status (see super new)

This is what i had as the table

```
<tbody>
  <%=  @data.each do |row| %>


    <tr><%= data.field1 %></tr>

    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

Was there something im missing? models? or what?

What i wanted was each row thats in the table to be added into the html table, at the moment all i get is a syntax error for *each*

Comment: It should be `<%  @data.each do |row| %>`     no need  a `=` in `<%=`

Comment: Still not working, Still got a syntax error on each

Comment: why was there a downvote?

Comment: I did not downvote you can you please post all of your views and errors log to solve it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You get a syntax error because you declare `row` variable and then use the undeclared `data` variable.

Here's the working version:

```
<tbody>
  <%=  @data.each do |data| %>
   <tr><%= data.field1 %></tr>

  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Can you show the error? What syntax error do you get?

Comment: NoMethodError at /admin/dashboard
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: `@data` variable is nil. Are you sure you're calling the right controller?

Comment: believe so, Its got othere carstatus stuff inside so like car_status.car_id = params[:car_id] works

Comment: although i might not be haha!

Comment: @ddsbro what do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85421/discussion-between-ddsbro-and-miguel-cunha).